# How do I run my Task in my ViewModel inside my ContentPage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a task in my viewmodel that looks like this:

```
    ICommand getWeather;
    public ICommand GetWeatherCommand =>
    getWeather ??
    (getWeather = new Command(async () => await ExecuteGetWeatherCommand()));

    public async Task ExecuteGetWeatherCommand()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            WeatherRoot weatherRoot = null;
            var units = IsImperial ? Units.Imperial : Units.Metric;


            if (UseGPS)
            {
                //Get weather by GPS
                var local = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000);
                weatherRoot = await WeatherService.GetWeather(local.Latitude, local.Longitude, units);
            }
            else
            {
                //Get weather by city
                weatherRoot = await WeatherService.GetWeather(Location.Trim(), units);
            }

            //Get forecast based on cityId
            Forecast = await WeatherService.GetForecast(weatherRoot.CityId, units);

            var unit = IsImperial ? "F" : "C";
            Temp = $"Temp: {weatherRoot?.MainWeather?.Temperature ?? 0}°{unit}";
            Condition = $"{weatherRoot.Name}: {weatherRoot?.Weather?[0]?.Description ?? string.Empty}";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Temp = "Unable to get Weather";
            //Xamarin.Insights.Report(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

How can I reach that Task and make it execute the function properly? 
My goal is for it to execute right when the user enters the contentpage (StartPage). Right now I use this code below but the Command does not execute.

```
    public StartPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        loadCommand ();

    }

    async Task loadCommand ()
    {
        var thep = new WeatherViewModel ();
        await thep.ExecuteGetWeatherCommand ();
    }
```

I bind the command into my listview:

```
  RefreshCommand="{Binding GetWeatherCommand}"
```

With my current code the Task does not execute. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, it will execute - if you stick breakpoint inside `ExecuteCommand`, you will see it's called  How are you certain it's not executing?

Comment: Check my updated code. I want the "ExecuteGetWeatherCommand" to run as soon as you enter the page

Comment: The code inside the viewmodel it works. If I use XAML  <Button Text="Get Weather" Command="{Binding GetWeatherCommand}"/> It works. But I do not want a button to make it execute. I want it to load immediatly

Comment: It *will* execute.  If I was guessing, the problem is you're creating a new ViewModel to execute the command, and this probably isn't the same ViewModel you're binding your button to.  The command will *definitely* get executed by your code, though.  Stick a breakpoint on it to prove it.

Comment: The button is binded to the command that executes the task. I am not sure hwo I can make it run immediatly though when u enter the page and do it without a button

Comment: Yes, but the button is bound to the command *on a different instance of WeatherViewModel*.  You need to execute the command on the ViewModel instance your Page is bound to, not just new up another one.

Comment: Could you show in code how you mean? I kinda get it but I am not quite sure how to execute it

Comment: Oh btw, something I might have missed to say. The Button Command that executes the task is binded into my listview liek this:  RefreshCommand="{Binding GetWeatherCommand}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your naming convention is odd, theTask is not a Task, so you probably should not call it one. Secondly, because you are calling loadCommand in your constructor and not awaiting it, its possible for the constructor to complete before the function is completed. In general, you want to avoid async in your constructor.

Stephen Cleary has a great article on async in constructors here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

What may be appropriate is attaching a handler to the Appearing event of your page, and do the async work there. Without more context it is a little hard to say if this is the best approach for your use case.

For instance:

```
public StartPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    Appearing += async (sender, args) => await loadCommand();
}

async Task loadCommand ()
{
    var viewModel = new StartPageViewModel();
    await viewModel.ExecuteCommand();
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to run... Hmm.. Posting the entire code. One second

Comment: The code inside the Task (in the viewmodel) works. If I use XAML  <Button Text="Get Weather" Command="{Binding GetWeatherCommand}"/> It works. But I do not want a button to make it execute. I want it to load immediatly

Comment: @medvedo Did you try my suggestion of putting it iin the Appearing event handler?

Comment: @medvedo Glad to help. One more suggestion though. The name "StartPageViewModel" suggests a problem with your design. In MVVM, layers should not really know anything about the layer above. So a ViewModel should not care about the View (aka, a page). It is okay for a ViewModel to wrap a Model for instance, but not for a Model to wrap a ViewModel. Maybe it is just your naming convention at fault here though, and not the actual design.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tips and feedback. I am not that used to viewmodels just yet so I appreciate all the help